# ruamel.yaml: clarification on typ and pure=True

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I am trying to understand what `typ` and `pure=True` mean in the `ruamel.yaml` Python library.
I've read the documentation [here](https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basicuse.html?highlight=typ).
So far, I've understood that `typ='safe'` uses a safe loader which omits YAML tags parsing in YAML (they can lead to arbitrary code execution).
I haven't found any explanation about round-trip parser `typ='rt'` in the docs.

Also, I think explanation on `pure=True` is confusing:

> Provide `pure=True` to enforce using the pure Python implementation (faster C libraries will be used when possible/available)

Are faster C libraries used with `pure=True` or not? If they do, why do you need to specify this flag in the first place?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are four standard `typ` parameters:

- `rt`: (for round-trip) in this case the document is loaded in special types that preserve comments, etc., used for dumping. This is what `ruamel.yaml` was created for and this is the default (i.e. what you get if you don't specify `typ`). This is a subclass of the `safe` loader/dumper.
- `safe`: this only loads/dumps tagged objects, when these are **explicitly** registered with the loader/dumper
- `unsafe`: try to load/dump everything. Classes are automatically resolved to a tag of the form `!!python/object:<module>/<class>`
- `base`: the loader/dumper from which everything is derived. All scalars are loaded as strings (even the types like integer, float, Boolean that are handled specially as mentioned in the YAML specification or the [type description](http://yaml.org/type/)

For `safe`, `unsafe`, `base` there is the faster C Loader available. If you install from the `.tar.gz` file these will only get compiled during installation when the appropriate compiler is available. If they are not **available**, because they could not be compiled, then they cannot be used.
There is no C version of the `rt` code. So it is not **possible** to use C libraries.

The word `pure` is for when you use Python only modules. The opposite would be "tainted": Python tainted with C extension modules. There is no `tainted=True` parameter. This is implicit (when possible/available, see previous paragraph) when `pure=true` is not specified, as the default for `pure` is `False`

---

In order to further confuse you: the above are the four basic (built-in) values for `type`. If you use plug-ins you can e.g. do

```
yaml = YAML(typ='jinja2')
```

as shown [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44515747/1307905)

---

Some of the above information is available from the [`YAML()` docstring](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/yaml/src/default/main.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#main.py-46), little of that however made it into the package documentation, primarily as a result of lazyness of `ruamel.yaml`'s author.

Comment: Thank you.  
Do you know how to check if C loader is present on my machine?  
Do I understand correctly that for the best performance, I need to have C library installed and provide `YAML(typ="safe")`?

Comment: Run the following using the Python version that you want to test (i.e. your virtualenv): `/path/to/python -c "import ruamel.yaml; print(ruamel.yaml.__with_libyaml__)"` (I assume you don't necessarily want to go looking for the shared object yourself). Yes for best perfomance `YAML(typ='safe')` which is the same as `YAML(typ='safe', pure=False)`