# Read the value in the YAML file from the Python script

Tags: python, bash, shell, gitlab, yaml

I have a Python script named `app.py` that has the value of the project ID,

```
project_id = "p007-999"
```

I hard code it inside the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file provided below,

```
# list of enabled stages, the default should be built, test, publish
stages:
  - build
  - publish

before_script:
  - export WE_PROJECT_ID="p007-999"
  - docker login -u "$WELANCE_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$WELANCE_REGISTRY_TOKEN" registry.welance.com

build:
  stage: build
  services:
    - docker:dind
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: docker:2375
  script:
    - echo $WE_PROJECT_ID
    - cd templates && pwd && yarn install && yarn prod && cd ..
    - docker build -t registry.welance.com/$WE_PROJECT_ID:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG.$CI_COMMIT_SHA -f ./build/ci/Dockerfile .
```

I would like to automate this. I think the steps for that will be,

> a. write the  `project_id` value from the Python script to a shell
>   script `variables.sh`.
>   b.  In the `before_script:` of the YML file,
>   execute the `variables.sh` and read the value from there.

How do I achieve it correctly?

Comment: @AliBenZarrouk its mention in the first line of the question. I have a python file `app.py` where the value is originally generated and acquired.

Comment: Gitlab uses the extension `.yml` although the recommended extension has been `.yaml` since Sep 2006 (see the FAQ on yaml.org). The file format acronym always has been YAML and never YML

Comment: @Arefe do you want the content of this `variables.sh` script shared between all the stages ? Or do you just want to `project_id` variable accessible to the `build` stage ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `ruamel.yaml`, which was specfically developed to do these
kind of round-trip updates (disclaimer: I am the author of that package).

Assuming your input is:

```
# list of enabled stages, the default should be built, test, publish
stages:
  - build
  - publish

before_script:
  - PID_TO_REPLACE
  - docker login -u "$WELANCE_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$WELANCE_REGISTRY_TOKEN" registry.welance.com

build:
  stage: build
  services:
    - docker:dind
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: docker:2375
  script:
    - echo $WE_PROJECT_ID
    - cd templates && pwd && yarn install && yarn prod && cd ..
    - docker build -t registry.welance.com/$WE_PROJECT_ID:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG.$CI_COMMIT_SHA -f ./build/ci/Dockerfile .
```

And your code something like:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml


def update_project_id(path, pid):
   yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
   yaml.indent(sequence=4, offset=2) # non-standard indent of 4 for sequences
   yaml.preserve_quotes = True
   data = yaml.load(path)

   data['before_script'][0] = 'export WE_PROJECT_ID="' + pid + '"'
   yaml.dump(data, path)

file_name = Path('.gitlab-ci.yml')
project_id = "p007-999"

update_project_id(file_name, project_id)
```

which gives as output:

```
# list of enabled stages, the default should be built, test, publish
stages:
  - build
  - publish

before_script:
  - export WE_PROJECT_ID="p007-999"
  - docker login -u "$WELANCE_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$WELANCE_REGISTRY_TOKEN" registry.welance.com

build:
  stage: build
  services:
    - docker:dind
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: docker:2375
  script:
    - echo $WE_PROJECT_ID
    - cd templates && pwd && yarn install && yarn prod && cd ..
    - docker build -t registry.welance.com/$WE_PROJECT_ID:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG.$CI_COMMIT_SHA -f ./build/ci/Dockerfile .
```

(including the comment, which you lose when using by most other YAML loader/dumpers)

Comment: My yaml is generated from the `jinja2` template and I get the error like `ruamel.yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning for the next token
found character '\t' that cannot start any token
  in ".gitlab-ci.yml", line 55, column 1`. However, I tested with a valid `yaml` file and seems your code is working.

Comment: You have a TAB character in your jinja2 template, make sure you expand those to the appropriate amount of spaces

Comment: Okay how do I properly format the Jinja2 template? Is there any online formattor available?

Comment: There is no jinja2 format, it is a templating language that can generate any (text) file you want. Just take an editor where you can see the tabs and delete them then insert spaces. You can do **a line at a time** and run the template expansion + above program to make sure you did not introduce YAML errors, until you are confident about your changes.

Comment: Hmm yaml seems not the best

Comment: can your code read the ‘.yml.j2’ files? I am thinking of using the Jinja2 template for the base of everything

Comment: Yes, most jinja2 for YAML can be edited, but you need a plug-in as the jinja2 makes for invalid YAML, Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44515747/1307905)

Answer (score 1):

This is almost definitely inappropriate, but I really can't help myself.

WARNING: This is destructive, and will overwrite `.gitlab-ci.yml`.

```
awk '
  NR==FNR && $1=="project_id" {pid=$NF}
  /WE_PROJECT_ID=/ {sub(/\".*\"/, pid)}
  NR!=FNR {print > FILENAME}
' app.py .gitlab-ci.yml
```

1. In the first file only, assign the last column to `pid` only if the first column is exactly "project_id".
2. On any line in any file that assigns the variable `WE_PROJECT_ID`, replace the first quoted string with `pid`.
3. In any files other than the first, print all records to the current file. This is possible due to `awk`'s nifty buffers. If you have to be told to make a back-up, don't run this.

Comment: Thanks, the answer provides good knowledge, but I wont use it