# Having trouble with yaml render in python ( multi line string )

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml

Here is my python function which i use to render a yaml template with any variables.
It works fine up untill i pass  multi line string to the sample file.

```
def render_template(template_path, context):
    """
    Render Jinja2 template using the provided context.
    """
    with open(template_path, 'r') as template_file:
        template = Template(template_file.read())
        return template.render(context)
```

Here is place from where i call the above function

```
        if centralized_data is not None:
            print("centralized_data is not None")

            rendered_template = render_template(input_template_path, context)
            sample_data = yaml.safe_load(rendered_template)

            # Ensure both sample_data and centralized_data are dictionaries
            if isinstance(sample_data, dict) and isinstance(centralized_data, dict):
                final_data = merge_data(sample_data, centralized_data)
            else:
                print("Error: Either sample_data or centralized_data is not a dictionary")
                # Handle the error condition appropriately
                final_data = {}
        else:
            print("centralized_data is None, using sample_data directly")
            with open(input_template_path, 'r') as template_file:
                sample_data = yaml.safe_load(template_file)
            final_data = sample_data
```

THe problem i believe is happening at
`sample_data = yaml.safe_load(rendered_template)`

this is where my multi string goes for a toss and looks something like this

input

```
deployment:
  annotations:
    proxy.istio.io/config: |
      concurrency: 1
      concurr222ency: 1
      concurrenc33y: 1
      f: 3
```

and output

```
deployment:
  annotations:
    proxy.istio.io/config: 'concurrency: 1

      concurr222ency: 1

      concurrenc33y: 1

      f: 3

      '
```

I also tried stuff like, but nope it does not help

```
proxy.istio.io/config: |>
proxy.istio.io/config: >-
```

Comment: I'm not sure I see the problem: the input yaml and output yaml are functionally identical, in both cases, `deployment.annotations.proxy.istio.io/config` has the same multiline value. The output is simply using a different -- but equivalent -- representation.

Comment: This output is later to fed into a tool called as FluxCD, although i have not got a chance to verify, if that complains about it, but yeah this seemed weird and i thought there would be a way to fix it ( even from a aesthetic point of view )

Comment: You can configure pyyaml to use the block quote operator (`|`) for multiline strings; see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45004775/147356

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are using PyYAML, and not only is it not really built to do this kind of round-tripping
YAML, as you experienced. It also only supports a subset of YAML 1.1, which was outdated in 2009.

I recommend using `ruamel.yaml` instead (disclaimer: I am the author of that package):

```py
import sys
from pathlib import Path

import ruamel.yaml

template_path = Path('template.yaml')
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
# yaml.preserve_quotes = True  # by default superfluous quotes are stripped
data = yaml.load(template_path)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
deployment:
  annotations:
    proxy.istio.io/config: |
      concurrency: 1
      concurr222ency: 1
      concurrenc33y: 1
      f: 3
```

As you can see the literal style scalar ( the three lines after the `|`) is preserved as is.

It also looks that that that literal style scalar contains valid YAML, if you load that after loading
the "template",
you can reinsert the dump of that, but it  will need  some care in order not to lose the literal scalar style.

Your input doesn't look like a Jinja2 template to me, those usually have `{{` and `}}`. And because of those you usually
cannot load a Jinja2 template
with a YAML parser, as there are Jinja2 constructs that make the template invalid. `ruamel.yaml`
has a [plugin](https://pypi.org/project/ruamel.yaml.jinja2/),
especially for these that converts the template to valid YAML so you can update the
parts that you want, and then converts it back to Jinja2. After that you can render it and
load the rendered text as valid YAML ( see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44515747/1307905)
or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69300709/1307905) answer )