# Ruamel yaml convert a yaml to jinja2 template without unwanted quotes

Tags: python, yaml, jinja2, ruamel.yaml

I have a YAML file and I am trying to convert a Jinja2 template for it.

The problem I face is for extra quotes while dumping the YAML file.

Sample YAML content:

```
- XYZ: 'Hispanic'
  age: 43
  hobbies: ['cycling', 'skating']

- ABC: 'American Indian'
  age: 43
  hobbies: ['ice hockey']
```

I plan to convert it to jinja2 template such as:

```
- {{ name }}: "{% include 'ethnicity.jinja2' with context %}"
  age: 43
  hobbies: "{% include 'hobbies.jinja2' with context %}"
```

where hobbies.jinja2 will be:

```
{% if name == 'XYZ' %}['cycling', 'skating']{% endif %}
{% if name == 'ABC' %}['rafting', 'ice hockey']{% endif %}
```

and ethnicity with be:

```
{% if name == 'ABC' %}Hispanic{% endif %}
{% if name== 'XYZ' %}American Indian{% endif %}
```

While dumping the YAML contents, I get:

```
- '{{ name }}': "{% include ''ethnicity.jinja2'' with context %}"
   age: 43
   hobbies: "{% include 'hobbies.jinja2' with context %}"
```

How can I remove the unwanted quotes for non-alphabetic strings here: `{{ name }}` and `2 single quotes for ethnicity`

In my use-case:

1. I will have to include a template from within a template.
2. I cannot change the input yaml.

And in doing so, another issue I face is hobbies become a string instead of a CommentedSequence.

ie. `hobbies: "['cycling', 'skating']"`

Comment: If you don't want quotes around the sequence, you should not include quotes in your template: `hobbies: {% include 'hobbies.jinja2' with context %}`

Answer (score 0):

**TL:DR** The YAML `- {{ name }}` is not valid Python because it uses a mapping/dictionary as a key for another dictionary. It is a compact way to write `- { { name: null } : null }` See @Anthon's answer for how to handle this.

At first glance, using `ruamel.yaml` (*not* the derivative `ruamel_yaml` package) to generate the following output

```
- {{ name }}: "{% include 'ethnicity.jinja2' with context %}"
```

does not seem possible because <strike>this is not valid YAML</strike> it specifies a mapping as a key to another mapping, which in Python would mean a dictionary would need to be the key of another dictionary, and this is not allowed because [dictionaries are not hashable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict).

Given a file name `template.yml` that contains

```
- {{ name }}: "{% include 'ethnicity.jinja2' with context %}"
  age: 43
  hobbies: "{% include 'hobbies.jinja2' with context %}"
```

I tried creating a round trip like so

```py
import io                                                                                                                                                                                                    [9/48]
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
import ruamel.yaml

def round_trip(path, yaml_type="safe"):
    yaml=YAML(typ=yaml_type)
    with open(path) as doc:
        yaml_obj = yaml.load(doc)

    yaml.default_flow_style = False
    yaml_fd = io.StringIO()
    yaml.dump(yaml_obj, yaml_fd)
    return yaml_fd.getvalue(), yaml_obj


## YAML types from https://sourceforge.net/p/ruamel-yaml/code/ci/default/tree/main.py#l53
# 'rt'/None -> RoundTripLoader/RoundTripDumper,  (default)
# 'safe'    -> SafeLoader/SafeDumper,
# 'unsafe'  -> normal/unsafe Loader/Dumper
# 'base'    -> baseloader
TYPES = ["safe", "rt", "base", "unsafe"]

PATH = "template.yml"

for t in TYPES:
    print(t, "==========\n", sep="\n")
    try:
        out, obj = round_trip(PATH, t)
    except ruamel.yaml.constructor.ConstructorError as err:
        print(str(err), end="\n\n")
        continue
    print(obj, end="\n\n")
    print(type(obj), end="\n\n")
```

which generated this output

```
safe
==========

while constructing a mapping
  in "template.yml", line 1, column 3
found unhashable key
  in "template.yml", line 1, column 4

rt
==========

[ordereddict([(ordereddict([(ordereddict([('name', None)]), None)]), "{% include 'ethnicity.jinja2' with context %}"), ('age', 43), ('hobbies', "{% include 'hobbies.jinja2' with context %}")])]

<class 'ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedSeq'>

base
==========

while constructing a mapping
  in "template.yml", line 1, column 3
found unhashable key
  in "template.yml", line 1, column 4

unsafe
==========

while constructing a mapping
  in "template.yml", line 1, column 3
found unhashable key
  in "template.yml", line 1, column 4
```

Hence, using `YAML(typ="rt")` did not raise an error when parsing the input.

I tried recreating the output from scratch with

```
>>> fd = io.StringIO()
>>> yaml.dump(ordereddict([(CommentedKeyMap(ordereddict([(CommentedKeyMap(ordereddict(name=None)), None)])), "value")]), fd)
>>> print(fd.getvalue())
!!omap
- {{name: null}: null}: value
```

which showed that it was trying to interpret `{{ name }}` as an implicit mapping with default values of `null`. This is allowed in the [YAML spec](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#mapping), as a mapping can be a key for another mapping object. However, this is not allowed in plain Python because a dictionary is not hashable and therefore cannot be the key in another dictionary. In otherwords, this is **invalid**

```py
# Raises TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
map_of_maps = {{"name": "val1"}: "val2"}
```

`ruamel.yaml` gets around this by wrapping the mapping in a `CommentedKeyMap` class, which is hashable.

I also tried parsing your expected YAML file with the [Online YAML Parser](https://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/), but that tool only supports YAML 1.1 as pointed out by @Anthon in the comments. (It also gave an error).

Comment: The package is `ruamel.yaml`, `ruamel_yaml` is a derivative made from an old version for an installer that cannot handle namespaces. Although `ruamel.yaml` cannot generate the output directly, it is has a pre- and post-processor for jinja2 templates of YAML documents that can.

Comment: The online YAML parser you reference only supports YAML 1.1 which has been replaced more than a decade ago with YAML 1.2

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure if you can generate the output that you want with `ruamel.yaml` or don't
know how to do approach that, it is always good to try and round-trip your YAML.

Of course a jinja2 template cannot be loaded without some pre-processing, as it isn't valid YAML,
which is what you can achieve by following the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44515747/1307905)
i.e. by installing `ruamel.yaml.jinja2` and instantiating `YAML(typ="jinja2")`,

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
- {{ name }}: "{% include 'ethnicity.jinja2' with context %}"
  age: 43
  hobbies: {% include 'hobbies.jinja2' with context %}
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='jinja2')
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
data[0]['age'] = 18
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
- {{ name }}: "{% include 'ethnicity.jinja2' with context %}"
  age: 18
  hobbies: {% include 'hobbies.jinja2' with context %}
```

The output equals the input, except for the expected change in the value for `age`. So
`ruamel.yaml`, when used with the `ruamel.yaml.jinja2` plugin, can handle this.

You should investigate what the data structure looks like, and you could try to generate
that from scratch, but there is a caveat in that the `YAML()` instance keeps some information
around about how the invalid jinja2 infused YAML document was transformed into a valid
YAML document, which is used during dumping.

In general the following will not work when handling jinja2 templates for YAML,
and adding the following:

```
yaml2 = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='jinja2')
yaml2.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

will generate an `AttributeError` because that extra information is missing.

You can investigate the missing attribute, but that is internal information that can
change without notice in a future version of `ruamel.yaml`.

If applicable the easiest way to go forward is to generate a minimal jinja2
template. You can use Python's `%` operator in order to circumvent having to escape
`{` as you would have to do with `.format()` or f-strings, but you will
have to escape jinja2's `%`. If you go with `.format()`:

```
yaml_str = """\
- {{{{ {var00} }}}}: "{{% include '{var01}' with context %}}"
  hobbies: {{% include '{var02}' with context %}}
"""

data = yaml.load(yaml_str.format(var00='name', var01='ethnicity.jinja2', var02='hobbies.jinja2'))
data[0].insert(1, 'age', 43)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

giving output:

```
- {{ name }}: "{% include 'ethnicity.jinja2' with context %}"
  age: 43
  hobbies: {% include 'hobbies.jinja2' with context %}
```

The above does expansion before loading.  You can recursively walk over
the loaded data and do expansion **after** loading, on keys, values
and elements that are strings. Some constructs (like jinja2 `{% if` are
converted to comments, so these will not be as easy to change. Because of
the interference of jinja2 using the characters `{}%` with both Python's
`%` operator and `.format()` you should probably tag the values to be
substituted with some seldom used special (unicode) codepoint instead
of that and use a special replacement.